# Thread safety of static blocks in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, static

Let's say I have some Java code:

```
public class SomeClass {
    static {
        private final double PI = 3.14;
        private final double SOME_CONSTANT = 5.76;
        private final double SOME_OTHER_CONSTANT = 756.33;
    }

  //rest of class
}
```

If a thread is initializing SomeClass's `Class` object and is in the middle of initializing the values in the static block when a second thread wants to load SomeClass's `Class` again, what happens to the static block?  Does the second thread ignore it assuming it's already initialized even though the first thread is not done? Or does something else happen?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If the first thread hasn't finished initializing SomeClass, the second thread will block.

This is detailed in the Java Language Specification in [section 12.4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2).

Comment: So, it would be initialized twice but not in parallel

Comment: @user454322: No, it will only be initialized once. The second thread will wait until the first thread has finished initialization before continuing - at which point it *won't* do the initialization again.

Comment: Because of _4. If the class or interface has already been initialized, then no further action is required.._ ?

Comment: @user454322: Yes, in conjunction with step 2 (block until the thread is informed that the class has been initialized, then repeat).

Answer (score 17):

Static class initialization is guaranteed to be thread-safe by Java.

Answer (score 2):

watch out that you dont call code that require the lock for the class being initialized - it will deadlock. see this blog post: http://ramblingabout.wordpress.com/2008/04/10/deadlock-quiz-the-answer/

Answer (score 0):

Static block is always thread safe while its getting initialzed. This is the reason use **static** variable of singleton object as one way of creating singleton object (singelton desing pattern).

Answer (score 0):

> Because the Java programming language is multithreaded, initialization
> of a class or interface requires careful synchronization, since some
> other thread may be trying to initialize the same class or interface
> at the same time

refered from [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2)