# ThreadLocal Initialization in Java?

Tags: java

I'm building a singleton that has a ThreadLocal as an instance variable, this singleton has a method that may be accessed by multiple threads and it is lazily instantiated. Right now I'm thinking on something like this:

```
static final ThreadLocal<HashMap> bindingContext = new ThreadLocal<HashMap>();
```

But I'm not sure if it is a good idea, I also have the option to make it an instance variable since I'm using it (as I said on a singleton).

So the question is, where is the best place to initialize that class variable or should it be a class variable at all?

Comment: what do u mean by "get called more than once under certain conditions by the classloader."

Comment: It is guaranteed that static initializers are executed in a thread safe way

Comment: @SurajChandran is that true? I had situations where static initializers were called twice.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/878577/are-java-static-initializers-thread-safe

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462697/thread-safety-of-static-blocks-in-java

Comment: basically, static initialisers are guaranteed to only be called once per-classloader

Comment: @MalcolmSmith I didnt know that, I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is guaranteed that static initializers are executed in a thread safe way. The JLS specifically mentions this:

> Because the Java programming language is multithreaded, initialization
>   of a class or interface requires careful synchronization, since some
>   other thread may be trying to initialize the same class or interface
>   at the same time. There is also the possibility that initialization of
>   a class or interface may be requested recursively as part of the
>   initialization of that class or interface; for example, a variable
>   initializer in class A might invoke a method of an unrelated class B,
>   which might in turn invoke a method of class A. **The implementation of
>   the Java virtual machine is responsible for taking care of
>   synchronization and recursive initialization** by using the following
>   procedure.

See section [12.4.2 of JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/execution.html#12.4.2) that describes this very thing in detail.

**EDIT**: And what you are trying is perfectly fine. From the javadocs of ThreadLocal:

> ThreadLocal instances are typically private static fields in classes
>   that wish to associate state with a thread (e.g., a user ID or
>   Transaction ID).

Comment: @tom No. There is no Exception. At the level of JLS, there is no ThreadLocal or anything. Its generic

Comment: +1 For the explanation, but it does not answer my question :)

Comment: if I understand the question correctly, it cannot be guaranteed that his singleton will return the correct object in a multi-thread environment since `ThreadLocal` is linked to the current thread. His singleton will return the object in the current thread.  I believe the singleton pattern in combination with `ThreadLocal` is a bad choice in this case.

Comment: @JuanAlbertoLópezCavallotti What part is not answered.what you are trying is perfectly fine. From the javadocs of ThreadLocal: "ThreadLocal instances are typically private static fields in classes that wish to associate state with a thread (e.g., a user ID or Transaction ID)."

Comment: @tom according to javadocs this itself is the recommended way of using a thread local. See my edited answer

Comment: Well, I must have understood the question wrong.  I thought he tried to share a state application wide.  No offense intended.

Comment: does it have to be static if my instance I get is going to be singleton?

Answer (score 1):

The static member will insure that a new ThreadLocal will be created, but the initial value of that ThreadLocal will be null for each new thread. You can easily provide a thread specific initial value by overriding the initialValue() method. One way to do that is with an anonymous inner class E.G.

```java
static final ThreadLocal<HashMap> bindingContext = new ThreadLocal<HashMap>() {
    @Override protected HashMap initialValue() {return new HashMap();}
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

with Lamda usage, we can write this way:

```java
private ThreadLocal<Map<String,String>> bindingContext = ThreadLocal.withInitial(HashMap::new);
```