# Is instantiating non final static variables Thread-Safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, design-patterns, thread-safety, jvm

is this two class are same?

```
public class SingleTone {

    // yes this is a bug what if i change the class this way
    //  private static SingleTone instance = new SingleTone();
    // and empty constructor?
    private static SingleTone instance; 
    private SingleTone() {
        instance = new SingleTone();
    }

    public static SingleTone getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class SingleTone {

    private final static SingleTone instance = new SingleTone();

    private SingleTone() {
    }

    public static SingleTone getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }
}
```

is there any thread-safety issue in none final variable instantiated by constructor?

Question 2:

what are Differences between

```
    private final static SingleTone instance = new SingleTone();

    private SingleTone() {
    }
```

and this:

```
    private final static SingleTone instance;

    private SingleTone() {
        instance = new SingleTone();
    }
```

Comment: To clarify more: if i rewrite my first example this way private static SingleTone instance = new SingleTone(); and remove constructor instanciation! whats the benefit of using final! ( i'm seeking thread safty issues not performance)

Comment: Both parts of the original version of your question contained bugs.  And your "clarified" question is now so confusing / confused as to be unanswerable ... IMO.

Comment: One point that can be answered is: with or without `final` the field is *effectively final* because it is guranteed to be assigned only once. It is thread-safe because the assignment happens at class-initialization time.

Comment: I didn't aware of bug in my question. thanks @cowls i got part of my answer however i still don't know thread-safety issues regard using static none final variables. I update my question and did my best to clarify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Queston 1**

Your first example doesnt work.

As if you make this call `SingleTone.getInstance()` before an object of that type has been created it will return null

Second example works fine

**Question 2**

Same situation, youre instatiating a static field in the constructor. This doesnt make sense as you cant guarantee the constructor has been called before accessing the static field.

You can do this instead:

```
private final static SingleTone instance;

static {
    instance = new SingleTone();
}
```

This will instantiate the static field when the class is first loaded.

---

Answering your comment.

If you do this:

```
private static final SingleTone instance = new SingleTone();
```

That is thread safe as if the first thread hasnt finished initializing the class and another thread tries to access it the other thread will block.

See this question for more info: [Thread safety of static blocks in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462697/thread-safety-of-static-blocks-in-java)

Comment: Yes you right what if i rewrite my first example this way private static SingleTone instance = new SingleTone(); and remove constructor instanciation! whats the benefit of using final! ( i'm seeking thread safty issues not performance)

Comment: updated answer as per your comment

Comment: thanks i got the bug! however in my comment i used none final variable not final variable. i updated answer please look at it again

Comment: Not sure I understand, but if you restrict access to the field via private constructors and not providing any set fields then you dont need final. ie using final will not make it any more thread safe

Answer (score 0):

The two options are in fact identical (but the `super()` call in constructor is missing in both cases).

However, implementing a singleton is Java using a private static field tends to be deprecated. Now, I would use an enum.

```
public enum Elvis {
    INSTANCE;
    private final String[] favoriteSongs =
        { "Hound Dog", "Heartbreak Hotel" };

    public void printFavorites() {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(favoriteSongs));
    }
}
```

If you want further readings: http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/creating-and-destroying-java-objects-par/208403883?pgno=3

Comment: i don't asked for implementing single-tone i'm aware of Enum way.

Answer (score 0):

SingleTone class must return an reference, so first example is totally wrong.

Consider the below process:
1. Class loading Started by JVM 
2. Class is loaded into JVM. 
3. Constructor Execution 
4. Object Creation completed

public class SingleTone {
    For this example instance will be alive between 1 and 2
    private final static SingleTone instance = new SingleTone();

```
private SingleTone() {
}

public static SingleTone getInstance(){
    return instance;
}
```

}

public class SingleTone {
    For this example instance will be alive between 3 and 4
    private final static SingleTone instance;

```
private SingleTone() {
    instance = new SingleTone();
}

public static SingleTone getInstance(){
    return instance;
}
```

}