# Java static block thread safety

Tags: java, multithreading

I am studying Java 11 concurrency model and I see that a true singleton can be obtained via [LazyHolder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom). In particular, that page says that:

> Since the class initialization phase is guaranteed by the JLS to be
>   sequential, i.e., non-concurrent, no further synchronization is
>   required...

Ok so I understand that the static fields are initializated only once in sequence (so

```
public class DatabaseQueries {

  private static Map<DatabaseActions, String> database = new HashMap<>();

  public static Map<DatabaseActions, String> getDatabase() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableMap(database);
  }

  static {
    database.put(
      DatabaseActions.LIST_CHIHUAHUA,
      "SELECT id, nome, immagine FROM chihuahua ORDER BY data_nascita DESC"
    );

    // more...

  }

}
```

Is the above code thread safe? Even if I have a static block AND a separate static initialization of a map!

---

I have found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462697/thread-safety-of-static-blocks-in-java) answer:

> Static class initialization is guaranteed to be thread-safe by Java.

Above I have a static block AND a static variable, does it make any difference? Are both initializated at class startup?

So my question is if static blocks and static variables (outside static blocks) are both guaranteed to not cause multithread issues

Comment: Read https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/safe-public-construction/ to get a detailed explanation of safe initialization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote

> Even if I have a static block AND a separate static initialization of a map!

which shows a wrong mindset. You don’t have separate initializations.

The code

```
public class DatabaseQueries {
  private static Map<DatabaseActions, String> database = new HashMap<>();
  static {
    database.put(
      DatabaseActions.LIST_CHIHUAHUA,
      "SELECT id, nome, immagine FROM chihuahua ORDER BY data_nascita DESC"
    );
  }
}
```

is identical to

```
public class DatabaseQueries {
  private static Map<DatabaseActions, String> database;
  static {
    database = new HashMap<>();
    database.put(
      DatabaseActions.LIST_CHIHUAHUA,
      "SELECT id, nome, immagine FROM chihuahua ORDER BY data_nascita DESC"
    );
  }
}
```

All initializers of `static` fields (except for compile-time constants) are merged with all `static {}` blocks into a single initializer, in the order of their appearance in the class declaration.

The thread safety applies to the completion of that single resulting initializer and subsequent reads of the initialized data.

So if the map is never modified after the class initialization, it is thread safe. It’s not necessary, but strongly recommended, to enforce the “no modification after initialization” rule:

```
public class DatabaseQueries {

  private static final Map<DatabaseActions, String> database;
  static { // keep variable declaration and initializer close for readability
    Map<DatabaseActions, String> map = new HashMap<>();// mutable ref during initialization
    map.put(
      DatabaseActions.LIST_CHIHUAHUA,
      "SELECT id, nome, immagine FROM chihuahua ORDER BY data_nascita DESC"
    );
    // more...
    database = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);// enforce read-only
  }

  public static Map<DatabaseActions, String> getDatabase() {
    return database;// no wrapping necessary, it’s already wrapped
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The class is considered 'initialized' once all static members are initialized/executed. In your case that's `database` and `static {}`. This is done single-threaded and before anything else can access the newly initialized class.

After that, the Java Memory Model guarantees that, despite lack of explicit synchronization, all changes finished before the class is initialized are visible to all operations that happen afterwards (similar with fields initialized by a constructor).

This does not mean it's thread-safe yet, because the `database` is a mutable object. If the class you specified is everything there is, then that alone still doesn't guarantee that no outside entity can access `database` (think reflection).

The best effort to make this thread-safe is to store the result of `Collections.unmodifiableMap(...)` in the static field instead.