# Java store reflected Method statically in class: Safe?

Tags: java, methods, reflection, static, singleton

Is something like the following 'safe' in Java, and why?

```
public final class Utility {

    private Utility() {}

    private static Method sFooMethod = null;

    public static void callFoo(SomeThing thing) {
        try {
            if(sFooMethod == null)
                sFooMethod = SomeThing.class.getMethod("foo");
            sFooMethod.invoke(thing);
        } catch(Exception e) {}  // Just for simplicity here
    }

}
```

My rationale would be that even if another thread writes to `sFooMethod` in the background and the current thread sees it suddenly somewhere during execution of `callFoo()`, it would still just result in the same old reflective invoke of `thing.foo()`?

**Extra question:** In what ways does the following approach differ (positive/negative) from the above? Would it be preferred?

```
public final class Utility {

    private Utility() {}

    private static final Method sFooMethod;
    static {
        try {
            sFooMethod = SomeThing.class.getMethod("foo");
        } catch(Exception e) {}
    }

    public static void callFoo(SomeThing thing) {
        try {
            if(sFooMethod != null)
                sFooMethod.invoke(thing);
        } catch(Exception e) {}
    }

}
```

**Background update from comment:**
I am writing an Android app and I need to call a method that was private until API 29, when it was made public without being changed. In an alpha release (can't use this yet) of the AndroidX core library Google provides a HandlerCompat method that uses reflection to call the private method if it is not public. So I copied Google's method into my own HandlerCompatP class for now, but I noticed that if I call it 1000 times, then the reflective lookup will occur 1000 times (I couldn't see any caching). So that got me thinking about whether there is a good way to perform the reflection once only, and only if needed.

"Don't use reflection" is not an answer here as in this case it is required, and Google themselves intended for it to happen in their compatibility library. My question is also not whether using reflection is safe and/or good practice, I'm well aware it's not good in general, but instead whether given that I *am* using reflection, which method would be safe/better.

Comment: why? what are you trying to achieve? sounds to me like an XY problem...

Comment: Are you trying to assign only method `foo()`'s reference? Or you are expecting other threads to store reference to other methods in the SomeThng class?

Comment: If it is restricted, then there is a reason for it

Comment: No code other than the code shown, it would only ever be assigned with `foo`

Comment: @pallgeuer then why are you worried about thread safety? If at max twice, the variable will be assigned to same method reference.

Comment: @onkarruikar Well that's exactly what my thought was, that it would indeed be safe despite the obvious race condition, but it feels like a 'wrong' thing to allow a race condition so I wanted to ask. Can you maybe post an answer explaining why you rationalise that nothing bad could possibly happen with my code (and whether the second version is preferable)?

Comment: Second approach is better - but don't eat the exception - wrap the exception in some `Error`/`RuntimeException`, and rethrow that. Not sure how android works, but OpenJDK's JIT can constant fold `static final` fields.

Comment: The first is broken, as in absence of a thread safe construct, the `sFooMethod == null` could see a write made by a different thread, evaluate to `false`, followed by the subsequent `sFooMethod.invoke(thing);` not seeing the write and leading to a `NullPointerException`. This doesn’t say anything about `Method`’s internal state. You should follow Johannes Kuhn’s advice and use the second but without swallowing exceptions. This doesn’t compile anyway if you don’t ensure that the final field is always and at most once assigned. And keep in mind that the mutable `setAccessible` must not be used.

Comment: @Holger Are you saying it's possible that a thread sees the write from another thread in one statement, but then "forgets" about it before it executes the next statement? I thought that would not be possible...

Comment: @pallgeuer these are two independent reads without thread safety. Each of them may perceive a concurrent write or not. So yes, the first read may perceive the write while the second doesn’t. That’s not about “forgetting” as reads do not remember previous reads. See https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/safe-public-construction/#_singletons_and_singleton_factories the `UnsafeDCLFactory` example and point 2 below it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to avoiding memory consistency errors is understanding the happens-before relationship. This relationship is simply a guarantee that memory writes by one specific statement are visible to another specific statement.

Java language specification states following:
[17.4.5. Happens-before Order](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5)

> Two actions can be ordered by a happens-before relationship. If one
> action happens-before another, then the first is visible to and
> ordered before the second.
>
> If we have two actions x and y, we write hb(x, y) to indicate that x
> happens-before y.
>
> If x and y are actions of the same thread and x comes before y in
> program order, then hb(x, y).

As, in your case, writing to and then reading from the static field are happening in same tread. So the `happens before' relation is established. So the read operation will always see effects of the write operation.

Also, all threads are going to write same data. At worse, all eligible threads will write to the variable same time. The variable will have reference to the object that got assigned last and rest of the dereferenced objects will be garbage collected.

There won't be many threads in your App which will enter the same method at once, which will cause significant performance hit due to lot of object creation. But if you want to set the variable only once then second approach is better. As [static blocks are thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462697/thread-safety-of-static-blocks-in-java).

Comment: “writing to and then reading from the static field are happening in same tread”—only if `sFooMethod == null` evaluates to `true`.

Comment: It seems @Holger is right. It is possible that `sFooMethod` is set to a partially constructed object in thread A while executing `getMethod()`. Thread A then keeps going with constructing `sFooMethod` as fast as it can, but thread B in the meantime may see that `sFooMethod` is not null, and attempt to invoke it before the object is fully constructed, or before thread B sees the constructive field writes made by thread A. It seems to be a similar problem to why naive double-checked locking doesn't work: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking#Usage_in_Java

Answer (score 1):

> Is something like the following 'safe' in Java, and why?

1. No I would not recommend using reflections, unless you have to.
2. Most of the time developers design their classes in a way, so that access to a hidden field or method is never required. There will most likely be a better way to access the hidden content.
3. Especially hidden fields and methods could change their name, when the library they are contained in is updated. So your code could just stop working suddenly and you would not know why, since the compiler would not output any errors.
4. It is also faster to directly access a method or field then through reflections, because the reflections first need to search for it and the direct access don't

So don't use reflections if you don't have to

Comment: This misses my question. I'm not asking whether reflection is fundamentally a good idea. Assuming I am using reflection and don't want to perform the reflective lookup every time, which of my two proposals are safe/better?

Comment: It would be better (as you did in your second example) to store the method. This way calling it will be way faster

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your goal is -- there is probably a better way to do what you're trying to do.

The second approach, with a static initializer, is preferable because your first implementation has a race condition.

Comment: I have updated the question with my goal. Can you elaborate in what way the race condition could be a potential problem?